# Is CSRF protection needed in case of OAUTH2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, csrf

I have a `REST application` created with `Spring Boot` and protected with `Spring Security Oauth2` support. I'm using `Cloudfoundry UAA` as third party token provider.

There's no session in the application and every request has to be accompanied with the Oauth2 token provided by `UAA`. Is it still necessary to protect REST services against `CSRF` attack?

As there's no way a malicious site can get a valid Oauth2 token from my UAA service.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CSRF` attack targets `Cookies` and `Basic` authentication header in general.

Since in my application none of these are being used `CSRF` protection is not needed.
Authentication starts with provided `Oauth2` token (No Basic auth) and request's state is forgotten as soon as response is returned (No session cookie).

References:

1. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/170414
2. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/166724/should-i-use-csrf-protection-on-rest-api-endpoints/166798#166798